# PostgreSQL: Exporting a database on Windows?

Tags: postgresql

I need to export a database I created to get the code for creating the database and inserting rows.

I understand there is a method of using pg_dump, but all the walkthroughs of using it I can find seem to be on Linux.

Can anyone tell me how to do this on Windows?

Comment: `pg_dump` works just the same on Windows, there is no difference (except for the slightly different syntax for file names)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is this meant to be via the SQL Shell? If so, once I get past the username stage, it won't let me type anything for the password EDIT: I discovered the password just shows up blank instead of bullet points.

Comment: You start a Windows command line (`cmd.exe`) and then run `pg_dump`: http://imgur.com/srGeShG

Comment: What did you try so far, and what did not work for you? Did you try to replicate any of the Linux examples on your Windows box?

Comment: It's easier to use PgAdmin on Windows if you are not used to working with the command prompt.

Comment: the windows command line seems like the most consistent way to get pg_dump to work on windows. windows Git Bash doesn't seem to work with pg_dump. there's no error and no output. my guess is the password prompt is getting lost somewhere

Answer (score 4):

You have to execute pg_dump located in the bin folder of your PostgreSQL install.
Ex : `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin`.

The command is `pg_dump -U *username* -p *port* -d *database* -W -f *filename*`

**All the parameters are case sensitive ! (Check your username !)**

- `U` is for specifying the user that will connect to the DB.
  If you don't specify it, pg_dump will use the login you're logged on with.
- `p` for the port. (Default is 5432)
- `d` for the database name
- `W` to force pg_dump to ask for password
- `f` the name of the file where the export should be stored. If you don't specify this, the dump will be displayed in the console.

Example :
`pg_dump -U postgres -p 5432 -d postgres -W -f c:\vm\dump.sql`

**You may need special permissions to export the file to some folders.**
*(i.e. : C:\program files\ requires administrative rights for writing.)*

Comment: And to restore simply do `psql -d newdb -f dump.sql`. See the examples
 here (at the bottom of the linked page):https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pgdump.html